# Python JSON loads - wrong encoding of file

Tags: json, python-3.x, character-encoding

in `Python 3.8.2` I trying to open the JSON file and read data from it. JSON file is encoded in UTF-8 but when I read it, final string seems as to by wrongly opened as ANIS.

Tried with Notepad++:

JSON file opened in UTF8:

```
"úterý, třicátého-prvního, sedumnáct v jedna dvacet dva"
```

Changed coding to ANIS:

```
"ĂşterĂ˝, tĹ™icĂˇtĂ©ho-prvnĂ­ho, sedumnĂˇct v jedna dvacet dva"
```

When I copy string directly to python file, it is read properly.

My program:

```
  import json  

print('Wrong characters:')
with open('C:/Users/Tony/Desktop/test.json',
                          'r') as jfile:
                        data = json.loads(
                        jfile.read())
print(data)

print('Ok Characters:')
data2 = json.loads('{ "td": { "1": { "as": "úterý, třicátého-prvního, sedumnáct v jedna dvacet dva"}, "2": { "as": "úterý, třicátého-prvního, sedumnáct v třináct dvacet dva"}}}')
print(data2)

print('System settings:')
import sys; print(sys.stdout)
```

Console output:

```
Wrong characters:
{'td': {'1': {'as': 'ĂşterĂ˝, tĹ™icĂˇtĂ©ho-prvnĂ\xadho, sedumnĂˇct v jedna dvacet dva'}, '2': {'as': 'ĂşterĂ˝, tĹ™icĂˇtĂ©ho-prvnĂ\xadho, sedumnĂˇct v tĹ™inĂˇct dvacet dva'}}}
Ok Characters:
{'td': {'1': {'as': 'úterý, třicátého-prvního, sedumnáct v jedna dvacet dva'}, '2': {'as': 'úterý, třicátého-prvního, sedumnáct v třináct dvacet dva'}}}
System settings:
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
```

[test.json file](https://easyupload.io/luxezr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to debug without the preferred encoding of your system. You can get it with:

```py
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
```

But I suspect that your encoding is not ASCII or UTF8. Since Python3, [`open` takes an argument `encoding`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You should try to specify the encoding `utf-8`.

```py
import json

with open('example.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(json.loads(f.read()))
```

Comment: Nice one. `print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))` show that system locale is `cp1250`. Setting `encoding='UTF8'` with `open` do the trick. Firstly I tried to change it with `json.loads()` but setting it there was deprecated.